# Calculate the binary split sum of a word

Tags: code-golf, string, base-conversion, binary

Take a string, `s` containing printable ASCII-characters as input, and output its "binary split sum". Need an explanation?

**How do you get the binary split sum?**

We'll use the string `A4` as an example in the following explanation.

- Convert the characters to binary, treating each letters as a 7-bit ASCII character

  ```
  A -> ASCII 65 -> 1000001
  4 -> ASCII 52 -> 0110100
  ```
- Concatenate the binary numbers into a new binary number

  ```
  A4 -> 1000001 & 0110100 -> 10000010110100
  ```
- Split the new binary number into chunks, where no `1` can have a `0` to its left. You should not split consecutive `1`s.

  ```
  10000010110100 -> 100000, 10, 110, 100
  ```
- Convert these binary numbers to decimal

  ```
  100000, 10, 110, 100 -> 32, 2, 6, 4
  ```
- Take the sum of these numbers:

  ```
  32 + 2 + 6 + 4 = 44
  ```

So, the output for the string `A4` should be `44`.

---

**Test cases:**

```
a
49

A4
44

codegolf
570

Hello, World!
795
```

Comment: I think this would have been a nicer challenge without the ASCII conversion step, just taking the (decimal) number after step 2 as input.

Comment: Well, `8372` actually.

Comment: @xnor, you might be right, and it would be cleaner. I had fun solving this in Octave though, and I hope others will enjoy solving it too :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>86</s> <s>81</s> 76 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks Adnan</sup>
<sup>-5 bytes thanks xnor</sup>

```python
s=0
for c in input():s=s*128+ord(c)
print eval(bin(s).replace('01','0+0b1'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcJBCoAgEADAu6/wtrsZodEhAg89Rc1AEBW1vm8NM5qW7M6VOx7Svzwd6Wi6TWrdRa4XOmKlhtS5f01EGxI2Wqov0TiPIBXMIIW0CojGgHODDw)

`for c in input():s=s*128+ord(c)` to do the ASCII conversion numerically, where `*128` is used to left shift `s` 7 times (steps 1 and 2)
`eval(('0'+new_bin).replace('01','0+0b1'))` to split and sum (steps 3, 4 and 5)

Comment: Nice trick with the `eval`!  Doing the [ASCII conversion numerically](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcJBCoAgEADAu6/wtrsZodEhAg89Rc1AEBW1vm8NM5qW7M6VOx7Svzwd6Wi6TWrdRa4XOmKlhtS5f01EGxI2Wqov0TiPIBXMIIW0CojGgHODDw) saves some bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Oḅ128BŒg;2/ḄS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@//cEeroZGF09FJ6dZG@g93tAT/P9z@qGmN9///6onqOgrqjiYgMjk/JTU9PycNxPZIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUBwA)

#### How it works

```
Oḅ128BŒg;2/ḄS  Main link. Argument: s (string)

O              Ordinal; map characters to their code points.
 ḅ128          Unbase 128; convert the resulting list from base 128 to integer.
     B         Binary; Convert the resulting integer to base 2.
      Œg       Group consecutive, equal bits.
        ;2/    Concatenate all non-overlapping pairs.
           Ḅ   Unbinary; convert from base 2 to integer.
            S  Take the sum.
```

Comment: I've missed that trick of base conversion before.

Comment: Ah, nice trick indeed!

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
YB!'1+0*'XXZBs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x/ppKhuqG2gpR4REeVU/P@/enJ@Smp6fk6aOgA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'A4'` as an example.

```
YB        % Implicit input. Convert to binary using characters '0' and '1'. 
          % Gives a char matrix, where each row corresponds to a number
          % STACK: ['1000001'; '0110100']
!         % Transpose. This is necessary because MATL uses column-major 
          % order when linearizing a matrix into a vector
          % STACK: ['10'; '01'; '01'; '00'; '01'; '00'; '10']
'1+0*'    % Push this string: regexp pattern
          % STACK: ['10'; '01'; '01'; '00'; '01'; '00'; '10'], '1+0*'
XX        % Regexp. Linearizes the first input into a row (in column-major
          % order), and pushes a cell array of substrings that match the
          % pattern given by the second input
          % STACK: {'100000'; '10'; 110'; '100'}
ZB        % Convert each string into a decimal number. Gives numeric vector
          % STACK: [32; 2; 6; 4]
s         % Sum. Implicitly display
          % STACK: 44
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

Code:

```
Çžy+b€¦JTR021:2¡CO
```

Explanation:

```
Ç                   # Take the ASCII value of each character
 žy+                # Add 128 to each value (to pad each with enough zeros)
    b               # Convert to binary
     €¦             # Remove the first character
       J            # Join the array
        TR021:      # Replace 01 by 021
              2¡    # Split on the number 2
                C   # Convert from binary to decimal
                 O  # Sum them all up
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4/ei@Su2kR01rDi3zCgkyMDK0Mjq00Nn//3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
Çžy+b€¦Jγ2ôJCO
```

A port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120601/53748), using the 128 offset from [Adnan's 05ab1e answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120594/53748) (rather than the 256 in the Jelly answer I wrote).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4/ei@Su2kR01rDi3zOrfZ6PAWL2f///@T81NS0/Nz0gA)**

#### How?

```
Çžy+b€¦Jγ2ôJCO
Ç              - to ordinals
   +           - add
 žy            - literal 128
    b          - to binary
     €         - for each
      ¦        -   dequeue
       J       - join
        γ      - group into chunks of equal elements
          ô    - split into chunks of
         2     - literal 2
           J   - join
            C  - from binary
             O - sum
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```
s=>eval(s.replace(/./g,c=>(128+c.charCodeAt()).toString(2).slice(1)).replace(/1+/g,'+0b$&'))
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes with some help from @ConorO'Brien.

Comment: My own solution was 97 bytes, too: ```s=>eval([...s].map(e=>(e.charCodeAt()+128).toString(2).slice(1)).join``.replace(/1+0*/g,'+0b$&'))``` You can use my replace method to save a byte, I think

Comment: @ConorO'Brien More than a byte, I think!

Comment: Oo, n​i​c​e :​D

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```js
c_¤ùT7Ãò< xÍ
c_           // Firstly, take the input and map over it as charcodes.
  ¤          // Take the binary representation of each item
   ùT7       // and left-pad it with zeroes to standardize the items.
      Ã      // After all of the above,
       ò<    // partition the result where ever a 0 precedes a 1.
          xÍ // Then sum the numbers from base 2.
```

Takes input as a single string.
I also tried out the 128 or 256 addition used by other answers, but 0-padding was shorter to use.

Shaved off a whole whopping 6 bytes thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) and [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it out here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y1+k+VQ3w/I8IHjN&input=IkE0Ig==)

Comment: You can use more auto-functions here: `òÈ<YÃ` can be `ò<` (with trailing space), and `Ën2Ãx` can be `xn2`. You can also use `T` in place of `0` to save on the comma. (Also, feel free to join us in the [Japt chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt) if you ever have questions or would like help with golfing :-) )

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks again, especially for the `T` trick, didn't know you could (ab)use variables for that, that's very handy. The auto-function `xn2` looks a bit weird when compiled, `x("n", 2)`, so I think it will still take a bit before I fully understand the logic behind them. With your help, the Japt solution is now tied for the first place with [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120603/16484).

Comment: ETHproductions recently made a shortcut for `n2` : `Í`. It hasn't hit TIO yet, but you can use it here: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y1+k+VQ3w/I8IHjN&input=IkE0Ig==

Comment: @Oliver Wow, that's very bleeding edge, that isn't even covered in the interpreter shortcuts reference yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Dennis (no need to flatten by 1 when a full flatten is fine - replace `;/` with `F`)

```
O+⁹Bṫ€3FŒg;2/ḄS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASYA2f//TyvigblC4bmr4oKsM0bFkmc7Mi/huIRT////ImNvZGVnb2xmIg)**

#### How?

```
O+⁹Bṫ€3FŒg;2/ḄS - Main link: list of characters, s    e.g. "A4"
O               - cast to ordinal (vectorises)        [65,52]
  ⁹             - literal 256
 +              - add (vectorises)                    [321, 308]
   B            - convert to binary (vectorises)      [[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]]
    ṫ€3         - tail €ach from index 3              [[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0]]
       F        - reduce with concatenation           [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]
        Œg      - group runs of equal elements        [[1],[0,0,0,0,0],[1],[0],[1,1],[0],[1],[0,0]]
          ;2/   - pairwise reduce with concatenation  [[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]]
             Ḅ  - convert from binary (vectorises)    [32,2,6,4]
              S - sum                                 44
```

Comment: `;/` can be replaced with `F`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 116 Bytes

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);)$r.=sprintf("%07b",$c);$t=mb_split("(?<=0)(?=1)",$r);echo array_sum(array_map(bindec,$t));
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2430f87c492fe9886e8ace92c12115099adeac35)

## PHP, 117 Bytes

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);)$r.=sprintf("%07b",$c);$t=preg_split("#0\K(?=1)#",$r);echo array_sum(array_map(bindec,$t));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JckxCsIwFADQvaeQNEI@LVInhxg6SAcRdHFTCWmapoE2Cb9xcPHqVXR78PZ1HGJmEANKNDFgct6ydyPPl@vx0ADPqELrBdGhMzaMPeFLH5BxqkXAjv32Rl1RPIADxY2YIzqfekbW1a4lJdXAaRIRjZVzHF1iJK/uJ1aLLeTfRuBGD2GlENVLzs@J/TWpyFrnO6NLmgD4snwA)

## PHP, 120 Bytes

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);)$r.=sprintf("%07b",$c);preg_match_all("#1+0+#",$r,$t);foreach($t[0]as$b)$s+=bindec($b);echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HcyxCsMgFEDRPZ9hX0ExlHTqYKVDydClXbqFIMYYFVKVp3N/PQ0dLwfu9ZZ9bixiQoU2J6whOvrt1fP1ftx7JhrQ6KIkJs3WpXUhYlsSUgFGJpzpXwcInI9MMMCTLBlDrAslx@4ykRYMExmtUx9djVd6XSk5nHnHD7thC5WJ/We18RTq0I26wMSgcDmFOFtD9xLW@ARFbNsP)

or

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);)$r.=sprintf("%07b",$c);preg_match_all("#1+0+#",$r,$t);echo array_sum(array_map(bindec,$t[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 21 bytes

It's too long...

```
siR2:.BiCMQ128"1+0+"1
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=siR2%3A.BiCMQ128%221%2B0%2B%221&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22a%22%0A%22A4%22%0A%22codegolf%22%0A%22Hello%2C+World%21%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [F#], <s>249</s> 245 bytes

```fs
open System
let rec c a=function|[]->[a]|'0'::'1'::y->(a+"0")::(c""('1'::y))|x::y->c(a+string x)y
let x i=c""(String.Join("",(Seq.map(fun c->Convert.ToString(int c,2).PadLeft(7,'0'))i))|>Seq.toList)|>Seq.map(fun c->Convert.ToInt32(c,2))|>Seq.sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fs-mono#bZFRa8IwFIXf/RV3gWHC2uKcInZYkL1sw4dBhT2ID1l6K4GYdE0cEfrfu7QVhrg8BHK/c@894ZgKNeRn6/A4UuhA6urkLKxg14zg@hBOIpgtn2/q61kHZrdAmAIPRpUBzxeTW/6KSpkIPk2tirsgWizn15pm33amahQggK/KkxZOGt3s9nG24/tmPBmn6fgxXN7GGeUPZEJYmlJBCL2UGWv8gEXg1tVSH8Azb/vvepCrTpz39eTdSE0JiWiO38mRVzRsBBFnL0b/YO2SrRmEVGoHIpqy5IMXGywdXUTBC2MyrMu6Zmc20rrL499Jb9o9TWk35KKyp2O7rmt@TkpTc6Wg76F9IhGgr1A4LBjEGVA/BMVCUH9gyG7UZFAFk67UQLZoQ5oVtxaLFO6/SNu2vw)

Note: the version on tio.run has "open System" in the header, I've added its count to the code above.
I'm not sure what the rules are on imports.

## Ungolfed

```fs
let rec convert acc = function
    | [] -> [acc]
    | '0'::'1'::xs -> (acc + "0") :: (convert "" ('1'::xs))
    | x::xs -> convert (acc + string x) xs
    
let calculateSum input =
    let binary = Seq.map (fun x -> Convert.ToString(int x, 2).PadLeft(7, '0')) input

    String.Join("", binary)
    |> Seq.toList
    |> convert ""
    |>Seq.map (fun x -> Convert.ToInt32(x, 2))
    |>Seq.sum
```

Comment: if `open System` is the same as C#s `using System;` then yes you need to include it in the count. If you can do it in F# you could fully qualify whatever the `System` is for . For example, in C# `System.Console...` instead of `using System;Console...`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It is the same, yes. Also, thanks for clarifying this :) I opted for the "open.." version because it's not only String, but also Convert that live in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.map{"%07b"%_1}.join.scan(/1+0*/).sum{_1.to_i 2}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3bXTtiquL9ZIqS1KL9XITC6qVVA3Mk5RU4w1r9bLyM_P0ipMT8zT0DbUNtPQ19YpLc6vjDfVK8uMzFYxqayFmrCxQcItWcjRRioXwFyyA0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 62 bytes

```
{sum map {:2(~$_)},.comb».ord».fmt('%07b').join~~m:g/11*0*/}
```

Comment: use `.ords` instead of `.comb».ord`. prefix `[~]` can often be used instead of `.join`. `comb` exists which does the `m:g/…` thing. `/11*0*/` can be shortened to `/1+0*/`. I came up with [`{sum map {:2($_)},comb /1+0*/,[~] .ords».fmt('%07b')}`](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY7NToNAHMTv/6cYm2p325XShkpaAtGbvXjRxIM1hsJiSBaWLIvREHwxb74YUmKv8/GbaWqJjxsnCaj4wlWiU4mwb@umQBFXaHdrNn3jnUh0ccRytXDnS/Hy/QpHm7T@/XGywrLZpesfZ7zrB8KtlbVFiOl8/@CovJQ1447RVhu2DqOV2FWxsXmseEDNsPw0pAOqVFxiMVYDyrT5p1xHYDjkZdVYgX1p2aM1HAf5WcnEyhQcLQF5jdNrNua4wNkWmLSj5lTSqA5hhPbsdRPq@pi8LdGdR55HdEK8a5XRxneJ7qVSWuBZG5VekL/d/AE)

Answer (score 0):

### mathematica 193 bytes

```
f=FromDigits;l=Flatten;(S=Split@l@Table[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2][[k]],7],{k,StringLength@#}];Plus@@Table[f[RealDigits@f@Join[S[[i]],S[[i+1]]],2],{i,1,Length@S-1,2}]+Last@l@S)&
```

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by doing `f=FromDigits;l=Flatten;` at the start, and then replacing all instances of those two functions with `f` and `l`.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
[:+/@(,#.;.1~1,1=2#.\,)(7#2)#:3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEG2lre@goaOsZ61nWGeoY2hrpKwXo6OpYa5spKlsZaxWasXFlZqcka@QpqCeqA5nOpog2Mn5Kanp@TlpCBGP1JycfB2F8PyinBRF9f//AQ)

### Explanation

```
[:+/@(,#.;.1~1,1=2#.\,)(7#2)#:3&u:  Input: array of characters S
                              3&u:  Get ASCII values of each character
                       (7#2)        Array with 7 copies of the value 2
                            #:      Convert each value to a base 2 array with length 7
[:  (                 )             Operate on those binary values
                     ,                Flatten it
                 2  \                 For each infix of size 2
                  #.                    Convert it to decimal from binary
               1=                     Test each value for equality to 1
             1,                       Prepend a 1
      ,                               The flattened binary values
         ;.1~                         Chop that at each occurrence of a 1
       #.                               Convert each chop from binary to decimal
 +/@                                Reduce by addition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
+/>#.&.>(1,}.|.1 0 E.|.b)<;.1 b=.,#:a.i.
```

usage:

```
+/>#.&.>(1,}.|.1 0 E.|.b)<;.1 b=.,#:a.i.'A4'
```

returns 44

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 150 bytes

```
#(loop[[c & C](for[i % j[64 32 16 8 4 2 1]](mod(quot(int i)j)2))p 0 r 0 R 0](if c(if(=(dec c)p 0)(recur C c 1(+ R r))(recur C c(+(* 2 r)c)R))(+ R r)))
```

Well I was hoping the conversion from ASCII to bytes was shorter than this. The actual loop body is quite short, using `r` to accumulate the current result and `R` to accumulate the total result. If the previous bit `p` is `0` and the current bit `c` is `1` then we split a new chunk and accumulate to `R`, otherwise we update the `r` and keep `R` as it was.

Answer (score 0):

## **Python** 123 bytes

```
lambda w:sum(map(lambda x:int(x,2),"".join(map(lambda x:bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(7),list(w))).replace("01","0:1").split(":")))
```

Updated, thanks to Martin Ender.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! All answers need to be either full programs or callable functions (as opposed to snippets where the input is stored in a hardcoded variable). The function can be unnamed, though, so including a `lambda w:` would be enough to make your answer valid.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't phrase that well. Your edit is still invalid because a) the input is hardcoded, b) If this is a full program, it doesn't actually print the result. For a full program you'd have to read the input from standard input or a command-line argument, and print the result to standard output. That's why I said it's probably easiest if you submit it as a function by adding `lambda w:`.

Comment: Ohhh, Ok, i get it, it would be enough like this: f=lambda w:sum(map(lambda x:int(x,2),"".join(map(lambda x:bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(7),list(w))).replace("01","0:1").split(":")))

Comment: yep, that's valid. You don't even need the `f=`, because we allow unnamed functions (unless you reference the function name for recursive calls).

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1vfSF89Ptq6IlatQq2uTt2qwkpHX8Nc2UgzRj0hU0UpOT8lNT0/J03p/38A)

**Examples:**

```
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$,"a"
49
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$"A4"
44
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$"codegolf"
570
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$"Hello, World!"
795
```

**Explanation:**

Convert to ASCII values, convert to 7-bit binary, flatten, find where differs, and against original list to find where `1`s differ. Cut at these indices, convert back to decimal and sum up:

```
+/2/'_[;x]&x&~~':x:,/(7#2)\'`i$ / the solution
                            `i$ / convert to integer
                     (7#2)      / draw from 2, 7 times => 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
                          \'    / decode each (convert to binary)
                   ,/           / flatten
                 x:             / save as x
             ~~':               / not-not-each previous (differ)
            &                   / and with
           x                    / x
          &                     / indices where true
     _[;x]                      / projection, cut x at ...
  2/'                           / encode each (convert from binary)
+/                              / sum up
```

**Bonus**

Managed a **31 byte** version in [K4](http://kx.com/download/) too, but as there's no TIO for it I'm posting my oK solution.

```
+/2/:'_[;x]@&x&~~':x:,/1_'0b\:'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 bytes

```apl
{+/2⊥¨(1∘+⊆⊢)∊¯7↑¨2⊥⍣¯1¨⎕UCS⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqbX2jR11LD63QMHzUMUP7UVfbo65Fmo86ug6tN3/UNvHQCpDso97Fh9YbHlrxqG9qqHPwo96ttUDNCuqJ6lxA0tEETCXnp6Sm5@ekgTkeqTk5@ToK4flFOSmK6gA)

**How?**

`⎕UCS⍵` - Unicodify

`2⊥⍣¯1¨` - encode each in binary

`¯7↑¨` - and pad to the left with zeros to 7 places

`∊` - flatten

`1∘+⊆⊢` - partition by self increased by one

`2⊥¨` - decode each from binary

`+/` - sum

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 73 bytes

```factor
[ [ "%07b"sprintf ] map-concat R/ (?<=0)(?=1)/ re-split [ bin> ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BSgMxEIbveYppQGjB3a6wZWlrWzypFw@KeCg9pOnsGoxJnEyhIj6N7@Mrrak5WPC/zA/fDPP/rdLsqX98uL27nkHr6VUxG9dBms9lUBSRst87o/0OIRAyvwcyjoGww0OAiG97dBrjnyvxwKQizIX4EJAklYRTDaBYQj3N7KqW/1md2fFp520rT9ikqTK8QWv9OTx5sruBzLCZTsSn6NewBnlWNVsZf8O2sElFQqG904rhfgzD1eWiGg1Xi4vROFUpYrCG09XWuGVehu8v2PRHE1npl7L/AQ)

- `[ "%07b"sprintf ] map-concat` Convert each code point in the input string to a 7-bit binary number string and join them all together.
- `R/ (?<=0)(?=1)/ re-split` Split into a sequence of strings down the middle of every `01`.
- `[ bin> ] map Σ` Convert each from binary string to decimal integer and sum.